# Circular reasoning in deriving the time that kohanim can eat terumah and the time that the evening Shema can be recited

Tags: talmud-gemara, mishna, shema, tractate-brachot, teruma

The very first Mishnah ([Berachot 1:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37939&st=&pgnum=62)) states that the earliest time for the recitation of the evening *Shema* is the time that *kohanim* can eat *terumah*:

> מאימתי קורין את שמע בערבין משעה שהכהנים נכנסים לאכול בתרומתן
>
> MISHNAH. FROM WHAT TIME MAY ONE RECITE THE SHEMA' IN THE EVENING? FROM THE TIME THAT THE PRIESTS ENTER [THEIR HOUSES] IN ORDER TO EAT THEIR *TERUMAH* ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_2.html); [capitals in original](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5014/13438))

The Talmud ([Berachot 2a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=2&format=pdf)) attempts to figure out what time this refers to:

> אמר מר משעה שהכהנים נכנסים לאכול בתרומתן מכדי כהנים אימת קא אכלי תרומה משעת צאת הכוכבים לתני משעת צאת הכוכבים מלתא אגב אורחיה קמשמע לן כהנים אימת קא אכלי בתרומה משעת צאת הכוכבים והא קמשמע לן דכפרה לא מעכבא כדתניא ובא השמש וטהר ביאת שמשו מעכבתו מלאכול בתרומה ואין כפרתו מעכבתו מלאכול בתרומה
>
> The Master said: FROM THE TIME THAT THE PRIESTS ENTER TO EAT THEIR '*TERUMAH*'. When do the priests eat *terumah*? From the time of the appearance of the stars. Let him then say: 'From the time of the appearance of the stars'? — This very thing he wants to teach us, in passing, that the priests may eat *terumah* from the time of the appearance of the stars. And he also wants to teach us that the expiatory offering is not indispensable,  as it has been taught:  And when the sun sets we-taher,  the setting of the sun is indispensable [as a condition of his fitness] to eat *terumah*, but the expiatory offering is not indispensable to enable him to eat *terumah*. ([Soncino tranlation](https://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_2.html))

This reasoning seems a bit circular to me. We only know that the time for *Shema* is *tzeit hakochavim* because that is the time for *kohanim* to eat *terumah*, but we only know that that is the time for *kohanim* to eat *terumah* because that is the time for *Shema*. So how do we know either one in the first place? According to the Talmud it appears that this Mishnah is the source for both the time for *kohanim* eating *terumah* being *tzeit hakochavim* and the time for *Shema* being *tzeit hakochavim* (from the fact that the two events are equated), yet the Mishnah doesn't mention *tzeit hakochavim* at all! It seems like we're going in a circle — we derive the time for *Shema* from the time for eating *terumah* but we then derive the time for eating *terumah* from the time for *Shema*. Thus, we seem to have no original source for either one stating that the time is *tzeit hakochavim*.

If the above wasn't so clear, we can rephrase it as follows:

The whole point of this Mishnah is to tell us the time for *Shema*. That means that prior to this Mishnah we don't know the time for *Shema*. The *Mishnah* tells us the time for *Shema* as a function of the time for eating *terumah* in order to also teach us the time for eating *terumah* (by informing us that it's the same as the time for *Shema*), which means that prior to this *Mishnah* we are not supposed to know the time for eating *terumah* either. The problem is that if prior to this Mishnah we don't know either time, then telling us that the two times are the same doesn't actually tell us what the time is. All we should know after reading this Mishnah is that *Shema* can be recited when *terumah* can be eaten and *terumah* can be eaten when *Shema* can be recited. But we should have no way of knowing that that time is *tzeit hakochavim*.

How can we understand how we derive the times for eating *terumah* and reciting *Shema* from this Mishnah?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92233/discussion-between-alex-and-al-berko).

Comment: We just had this question going through the daf tonight. One thing we concluded is that according to the Maaravim there’s no problem - we derive Kohanim from Shema. But according to Rabbah, and certainly the Gemara’s original answer, it does leave the question open.

Comment: @DonielF If we derive kohanim from Shema then how do we know Shema?

Comment: The passuk in Nechemiah, via the Braisa cited there.

Comment: @DonielF If that's valid, why can't the same be true for the first version? But more importantly, it then comes out that the Mishnah is not actually teaching us the time for Shema, which seems a bit odd considering that it opens with מאמתי קורין.

Comment: @Alex The biggest question I have on this is: why? I understand that מילתא אגב אורחא קמשמע לן, but what does it have to do with Shema that the Tanna sticks it in here of all places?

Comment: @DonielF I don’t think there necessarily needs to be a specific connection between Shema and terumah. I think the point is that the tanna took the opportunity to lump them together so that when you study one you will automatically be reminded of the other. This way you get two laws for the price of one.

Comment: It was know when is haarev shemesh. It was know that we search an hour of the evening. But it wasn't known that a kohen mechusar kapara, e.g. who needs to give Korban for zav can still eat teruma. So we learn simultaneously the zman of is and that mechusar kapara can eat teruma

Comment: I think what is known is impure people become pure at nightfall, and what is being taught is both that the moment of nightfall is the time for shema AND that priests can eat terumah before bringing attonemnt offerings ("mechusrei kappara") since you may have thought their becoming pure at nightfall was not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the answer is as follows:

The Talmud immediately cites a *beraita* which discusses a Scriptural derivation for the time when *terumah* can be eaten:

> כדתניא ובא השמש וטהר ביאת שמשו מעכבתו מלאכול בתרומה ואין כפרתו מעכבתו מלאכול בתרומה וממאי דהאי ובא השמש ביאת השמש והאי וטהר טהר יומא דילמא
>
> as it has been taught:  And when the sun sets we-taher,  the setting of the sun is indispensable [as a condition of his fitness] to eat terumah, but the expiatory offering is not indispensable to enable him to eat terumah. But how do you know that these words 'and the sun sets' mean the setting of the sun, and this 'we-taher' means that the day clears away? It means perhaps: And when the sun [of the next morning] appears, and we-taher means the man becomes clean?  — Rabbah son of R. Shila explains: In that case, the text would have to read we-yithar.  What is the meaning of we-taher?  The day clears away, conformably to the common expression, The sun has set and the day has cleared away.
>
> ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_2.html))

We see here that there are two ways to interpret the verse. One way would have the time for eating *terumah* as nightfall, while the other would have it the next morning. By linking this law to the recitation of the evening Shema, the Mishnah automatically eliminates the second reading of the verse. It can't be that *terumah* can't be eaten until the next day, because the time for reciting the evening Shema obviously can't be the next morning. Thus, the Mishnah is not telling us the precise time for when *terumah* can be eaten; it merely points us to one of the two already known possibilities. Once we know which of the possibilities it is we can then apply that time back to the Mishnah as the time for reciting Shema.

(This answer is at least somewhat inspired by the Rashba's commentary on this passage, but I'm not sure if this is actually what the Rashba means.)

Comment: Why does ביאת אורו mean "when the sun [of the next morning] appears"? Compare Sefaria's translation https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.2b.1

Comment: @DoubleAA Isn’t that the machlokes Rashi and Tosafos?